# How To Centre a Navigation Bar that has Dropdown Menus

Tags: html, css, navigation

I have created this simple top navigation bar with a dropdown menu, I am trying to get all the links, including the dropdown menu, centered.

I have looked for and tried different ways to centre it all so that it auto adjusts  when used in mobile, tablet or screen with small resolution, however I am only managing to centre the dropdown menu or the other links, but not everything... How can I do this?

This is the code I'm using

````
body 
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #221a57;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  min-width: 192px;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #F73D4B;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="/home">Home</a>
  <a href="/about">About</a>
  <a href="/articles">Articles</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Freebies 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="/eguide">eGuide</a>
      <a href="/wallpapers">Wallpapers</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```
````

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [mcve]. This will increase your chance to get an appropriate answer. Furthermore it also helps you solving the question yourself.

Comment: remove the float  the min-width the overflow and use display:flex;  justify-content:center;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use display:flex; justify-content:center; and then you can fix the width as you you want you dont need overflow

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
     
    .navbar {
     
      background-color: #221a57;
      display:flex;
      justify-content:center;
    }
     
    .navbar a {
      font-size: 16px;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }


    .dropdown .dropbtn {
      font-size: 16px;  
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      color: white;

      padding: 14px 16px;
      background-color: inherit;
      font-family: inherit;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
      background-color: #F73D4B;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #DDDDDD;
     
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {

      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="navbar">
      <a href="/home">Home</a>
      <a href="/about">About</a>
      <a href="/articles">Articles</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Freebies 
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="/eguide">eGuide</a>
          <a href="/wallpapers">Wallpapers</a>
        </div>
      </div> 
      <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Many thanks, it works! However, if this goes to mobile, part of the menu will stay out of view... any way to solve this?

Comment: ive tested it its responsive

Comment: Hi yes [here](https://gallery.mailchimp.com/0fde44e063e494868a06d7cab/images/a30455ab-b303-4c35-9445-1f0f727b632f.jpeg) I am using this site for test: https://kensho.life/photoblog (forget about the text menus above the blue bar)

Comment: hello @thatguyreally yeah i can see it you have paddings and widths thats why

Comment: are you using javasript on this section or a plugin?

Comment: Hi @godfather many thanks and sorry I took the widths out but if I take the paddings it looks awful! And it seems to make no difference in any case... No javascript or plugin in the section, I'm simply using the code widget available in Squarespace

Comment: Ok try to add on nav padding-top and padding-bottom

Comment: Im working on something when i finish ill try to find a better solution

Comment: @thatguyreally hello sorry for being late but i had something urgent i made some changes   hope that will help you im creating a repo on github are you on github?

Comment: no worries I am not under a tight deadline on this I appreciate the help! I am not on github, but will get on it now

Comment: I am now on github as @thatguyreally :)

Comment: in command line  copy paste this :  git clone https://github.com/jadcoding/New.git

Comment: if something need to fix tell me

Comment: np if you need something else tell me